# Is the lebesgue measure of all the conjugate points of a point in an pseudo-riemannian manifold zero?

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a pseudo-riemannian manifold. Let $p\in M$. Let $\mathcal{D}_p$ be the maximal domain of the exponential map $T_pM\supseteq\mathcal{D}_p\xrightarrow{\exp_p}M$. Define the set of conjugate points of $p$ as $$
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{Conj}(p)&\equiv\left\{X\in \mathcal{D}_p\mid T_pM \xrightarrow{d\left(\exp_p\right)_X}T_{e^X}M \text{ is singular}\right\} \\
&=\left\{X\in \mathcal{D}_p\mid \text{there is a non-zero jacobi field between } p \text{ and }e^X\text{ along }\gamma(\lambda)=e^{\lambda X} \text{ that vanishes at } p \text{ and } e^X \right\}
\end{align*}$$
Is the lebesgue measure of $\mathbf{Conj}(p)$ zero? In order to define the lebesgue measure one needs to set up a basis in $T_pM$. But whether it is zero is independent of choice of basis.

Comment: Since I am viewing $\mathbf{Conj}(p)$ as a subset of $T_pM$ and not $M$, I think $\mathbf{Conj}(p)$ can be uncountable. I imagine that if $p$ has a conjugate point in $q\in M$, then $\exp_p^{-1}(\{q\})$ can be uncountable.

Comment: You really want to define conjugate points as as set of points in the tangent space rather than on the manifold? For example, for a sphere, if $p$ is the north pole then there will be a whole circle of $X$ which correspond to the south pole. Edit: I hadn't seen the above comment.

Comment: Yes! @PratyushSarkar. There will be uncountably many circles. And the union of all those circles will have lebesgue measure zero.

Comment: I haven't carefully checked but for the set of conjugate points on the *manifold*, Sard's theorem might do it. Not sure what happens to the corresponding set of points in the tangent space.

Comment: Sard's theorem answers the question for conjugate points on the *manfold*.

Comment: Sorry, I meant countably in a previous comment